# OpenCV imwrite doesn't save the image

Tags: c++, opencv

Im using a Basler camera, and I'm trying to save the grabbed image with OpenCV. However, when i try to use imwrite(), I get this error:

imwrite_('C:/Users/Uporabnik/Desktop/slika.png'): can't write data: unknown exception

My conversion of the grabbed image:

```
openCvImage = Mat(image.GetHeight(), image.GetWidth(), CV_16U, (uint8_t *)image.GetBuffer());
```

Trying to save the image:

```
cv::imwrite("C:/Users/Uporabnik/Desktop/slika.png", openCvImage);
```

Comment: Probably your conversion is not correct, try with CV_8UC1, instead of CV_16U. Also be sure that basler buffer isn't deallocated while you're using it

Comment: Maybe try to `cv::imshow`ing it first. You may also want to share some more code with Basler camera configuration. But I suspect incompatible Basler PixelFormat you are using while capturing images - make sure its 16 bit aligned (so either 16 bit or 12 NOT packed).

Answer (score 0):

I am also using basler camera. You also need to share codes which includes basler configurations.Here is how I used basler camera to get frame in the format of opencv:

```
#include <pylon/usb/BaslerUsbInstantCamera.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>    

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace Pylon;
using namespace GenApi;
using namespace Basler_UsbCameraParams;

int main()
{
Mat openCvImage;
Pylon::PylonAutoInitTerm autoInitTerm;
CBaslerUsbInstantCamera camera(CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice());
CImageFormatConverter formatConverter;
CPylonImage pylonImage;

    camera.MaxNumBuffer = 1;
    formatConverter.OutputPixelFormat= PixelType_BGR8packed;
    camera.StartGrabbing( c_countOfImagesToGrab);
    const uint8_t *pImageBuffer = (uint8_t *) ptrGrabResult->GetBuffer();
    formatConverter.Convert(pylonImage, ptrGrabResult);
    openCvImage= cv::Mat(ptrGrabResult->GetHeight(), ptrGrabResult>GetWidth(), CV_8UC3, (uint8_t *) pylonImage.GetBuffer());

      imshow("Basler Frame",openCvImage);
      waitKey(0);
      return 0;
}
```

But first of all you need to use "imshow" function to see image. 
If you can, the problem is in your directory part. Otherwise you need to share code about initiating basler camera.

Answer (score 0):

Please just pay attention to the dimension of your image, you can simply print and see if the shape is correct. In my case, I include the batchsize dimension to the image shape by mistake, and I solve it by image = image[0].